# map string filed to generic list in automapper based on .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I have a `DomainModel` and a `DTO` like this :

```
 public class PostEntity: IEntity
{
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public PostStatus Status { get; set; }
    public User Writer { get; set; }
    public int WriterId { get; set; }
}
  public class PostDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; }
    public List<string> TagList { get; set; }
    public PostDto()
    {
        TagList = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

`PostEntity'Tags` contains some tags seperated by `","`, now I want to split tags value by `","` and convert it to  List, to do this, I've tried this but I get the below compilation error

```
 CreateMap<PostEntity, PostDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.TagList, cc => cc.MapFrom(src => src.Tags.Split(",").ToList()));
```

I get this error :

> An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error, it seems to work fine.

Below is an example where the TagList is correctly mapped

[image]

The code I used :

```
MapperConfiguration MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(configuration =>
                {
                    configuration
                        .CreateMap<PostEntity, PostDto>().ForMember(dest => dest.TagList, cc => cc.MapFrom(src => src.Tags.Split(',').ToList()));

                });

                IMapper mapper = MapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();

                PostEntity postEntity = new PostEntity
                {
                    Tags = "Tag1,Tag2,Tag3,Tag4"
                };

                var mappedObject = mapper.Map<PostEntity, PostDto>(postEntity);
```

Comment: I am using `ASP.NET Core` do you think it might be beacaus of that? I mean maybe in this version the way to map it would be different

Comment: I wouldn't think .NET Core would matter but you could try using .NET Framework and see if your hypothesis is right

Answer (score 0):

Please bear in mind that Expression.Call API does not support optional parameters. So, you should Replace `Split(',')` with

`Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.None)`

or

`Split(',', System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

doing so you won't see that error again.